# Вывести конкретное поле возвращаемой строки модели Dajngo

Tags: python, django

Это похоже простой вопрос.
Есть модель, где по умолчанию возвращаю несколько полей

```
 def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.id, self.name, self.code, self.level, self.parent)
```

Как впоследствии при `Model.objects.all()` получить только одно конкретное поле

Пробовал как-то так, но не выходит:

```
p = ProductCategory.objects.all()
    print(p.name)
```

Comment: из доков ''For example, this returns the first 5 objects (LIMIT 5):

>>> Entry.objects.all()[:5] ''  такая штука не поможет ? по срезу/ индексу достать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Model.objects.all()` должен возвращать список объектов.
Если вы хотите получить поле только первого объекта, то используйте доступ по нулевому индексу:

```py
products = ProductCategory.objects.all()
    print(products[0].name)
```

Если вы хотите получить поле для каждого объекта используйте цикл:

```py
products = ProductCategory.objects.all()
    for product in products:
        print(product.name)
```

А с помощью генератора вы можете извлечь поля из всех объектов и сохранить их в список:

```py
products = ProductCategory.objects.all()
    names = [product.name for product in products]
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод `__str__` относится конкретно к объекту.
При `p = ProductCategory.objects.all()` конкретно в `p` у вас храниться не объект, а `QuerySet` и у него точно нет атрибута `name`. Что бы вывести `name` вам можно использовать либо `for`

```
p = ProductCategory.objects.all()
for obj in p:
    print(obj.name)
```

либо можно получить сразу массив имён

```
p = ProductCategory.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
```